# Show text without format

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML to plain text in PHP for e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail)

I've a HTML code make with a WYSIWYG (CKEditor) and this introduce DIV, P, SPAN and some others in my HTML which cause the HTML do not display like others. Exists any way to remove those extra markups with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a function name `strip_tags`, for more detail, please read the official document at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php