# Why won't Outlook use the text/plain part?

Tags: outlook, plaintext

First of all, hello,

With SwiftMailer, i'm sending HTML+PLAIN emails.

On outlook, when displaying this email as plain text, this is not my plain text part showing up, but a automatic parsed version of the HTML.

**Does anyone know how to force Outlook to use the text/plain part of  message when displaying plain text?**

My code does the following:

```
$plain_body = convert_html_to_text($body);
$message->setBody($body, 'text/html')
->addPart($plain_body, 'text/plain');
```

`$body` has some formatting and images:

```
vardump($body);

<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<img src="logo.png" alt="Company name" /><br />
<img src="border.png" alt="border" /><br />
<img src="face.png" alt="Mr Somebody" /><br />
<p>Hello Ninj!

You requested a confirmation by email...</p>
<img src="footer.png" alt="footer" />
</body></html>
```

`$plain_body` contains a very clean text (thanks *javon*):

```
vardump($plain_body);

"Hello Ninj!

You requested a confirmation by email..."
```

But in the plain text version viewed in Outlook, i see instead all the `alt` attributes of pics of the HTML version, one by line, then some lightly formatted text:

> Company Name
>
> border
>
> Mr Somebody
>
> Hello Ninj!
>
> You requested a confirmation by email...
>
> Footer

Thank you by advance for everyone able to help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't do that. Outlook keeps all 3 body flavors (HTML, RTF, plain text) in sync. This is done on the store provider level.

When it receives a MIME message, it uses the HTML body (if available). When the message is saved, the store provider uses the HTML body to generate the plain text body (PR_BODY property).

Comment: Thank you for answering, allow me to try to go further: why should we then include a text/plain version of the text if Outlook do not care about it? Isn't this alternative body made for that very purpose: show up instead of HTML when HTML is not rendered?

Comment: If you are sending to Outlook, plaint text won't do anything unless it is the only body part. Remember that Outlook does not store the messages in MIME format. Once a message is received from a POP3/IMAP4/etc. server and stored in an Outlook store, Outlook has no memory where the message came from and what its MIME format was.

Comment: @Ninj: There is not only Outlook out there; other clients will use the `text/plain` part. SpamAssassin dislikes mails which are HTML-only.