# Is this a good way to save the "plain" version of HTML content in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I need to save the "plain" version of HTML content coming from a textarea with a WYSIWYG editor. Right now I'm using the following function right before saving into the database:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
{
    if (($resource = $event->getEntity()) instanceof Resource) {
        $resource->setPlainContent($this->computePlainContent($resource));
    }
}

protected function computePlainContent(Resource $resource)
{
    return preg_replace(
        '/\s+/',
        ' ',
        html_entity_decode(
            strip_tags($resource->getContent()),
            ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401
        )
    );
}
```

Plain text will be used for searching among pages.

Questions:

- is this good/safe**, assuming the editor will always produce valid HTML?
- would you remove punctuation mark, and how?
- should I use `ENT_HTML401` or `ENT_XHTML` with CKEditor (default configuration, don't know the output quality)?

** for safe I mean safe to produce a good output. Users (o this system) are trusted.

Comment: You should always check server side the user inputs.

Comment: @FezVrasta are you talking about content or plainContent? By the way our users are trusted.

Comment: Of course it's not safe lol. You're transforming things like `&gt;` into `>` using html_entity_decode()

Comment: @onetrickpony I'm stripping tags right before decoding...

Comment: `&lt;script&gt;` is not a tag, you're making it a tag

Comment: @onetrickpony I understand now. I've updated the question, "safe" for good output point of view. My bad.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail

Comment: Just to add my two bits: You can also use jquery to get the plaintext. As for the &gt; etc, that can cause real problems if your data is not 100% managed by CKE, take a look for example at http://jsfiddle.net/qdndP/129/ - check the source HTML, then check what is displayed in the Editor and then check the editor source mode. As you see, CKE has some pretty cool logic in it to crunch tags, but they are expected to follow a good rule set. If that content was written in CKE (even in source mode!), it would be fine. Is this done for indexing / search reasons?