# parse php for strings to translate

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have many php files full of html markup. I would like to extract all the strings (**html node content and attribute values**), to generate a text document to review then send for translation.

I'm wondering, is there a reliable way (a tool or a script perhaps) that would do that automatically?

Example code i have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-11 columns medium-centered">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Bienvenue sur votre compte, vous permettant
            de répondre aux offres d'emploi. Tenez à jour vos données
            personnelles et vos documents officiels tels que CV, diplôme ou
            permis de conduire, et retrouvez l'historique des offres auxquelles
            vous aviez postulé.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<dl class="tabs" data-tab="">
    <dd class="active">
        <a href="#profile"><i class="fi-torso"></i> Votre profil</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="#formation"><i class="fi-bookmark"></i> Formation</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="#experience"><i class="fi-shuffle"></i> Expérience</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="#documents"><i class="fi-paperclip"></i> Documents</a>
    </dd>
    <dd>
        <a href="#history"><i class="fi-foundation"></i> Historique</a>
    </dd>
</dl>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="USERID">
<input type="radio" name="sexe" value="2" id="Monsieur" title="veuillez indiquer votre genre">
```

What i would like to extract:

```
Bienvenue sur votre compte, vous permettant de répondre aux offres d'emploi. Tenez à jour vos données personnelles et vos documents officiels tels que CV, diplôme ou permis de conduire, et retrouvez l'historique des offres auxquelles vous aviez postulé.
Votre profil
Formation
Expérience
Documents
Historique
veuillez indiquer votre genre
```

Comment: You can use a `HTML2PDF` to convert the html code to PDF.

Comment: I need it in text format.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail

Answer (score 2):

To remove all the tags in the HTML, you can use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/strip_tags):

```
$text_only = strip_tags($html_codes);
```

For document generation part, it depends what kind of document you want to generate.

Comment: that would not catch the html attribute values.

Comment: maybe you should give an example of output content.

Comment: `strip_tags()` will work for you, but you need extra transform to change line ( and escape characters ).

Comment: but in your output example, it does not show any html attributes.

Comment: I see. Finally noticed that. For the radio button, you may have to handle it by replace string / regex before you use `strip_tags()`