# HTML text to PHP image

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to take a piece of HTML, ie:

`<p>This is a nice test</p><p><br></p><p></p><ol><ol><li>We have a great product!</li><li>Our store is awesome!</li><li>We love what we do, which makes us really good at it!</li></ol></ol><p></p>`

And get it printed onto an image, centered for the size of this certain piece of HTML.

I don't care much if it will become a JPG, PNG or whatever, but i would like to have an image the size of 1080p or so (1920x1080), not sure if that even matters.

I can create an image with a string printed in the center, using something like this:

```
    $image = imagecreate( 1920, 1080 );
    $rgb = $this->hex2rgb($data['color']);
    $background = imagecolorallocate( $image, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2] );
    $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $image, 255, 255, 0 );
    imagecenteredstring( $image, 4, 210, 1710, 540, '<p>This is a nice test</p><p><br></p><p></p><ol><ol><li>We have a great product!</li><li>Our store is awesome!</li><li>We love what we do, which makes us really good at it!</li></ol></ol><p></p>', $text_colour );
    $tmpPath = '/tmp/' . strtotime('now') . '.jpg';

    imagesetthickness ( $image, 5 );
    header( "Content-type: image/jpeg" );
    imagejpeg( $image, $tmpPath);
    imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
    imagecolordeallocate( $background );
    imagedestroy( $image );
```

where `hex2rgb` is a function to convert the rgb input, this works, and where `imagecenteredstrng` takes a string and centers it onto an image, this also works.

So my main issue is how to "translate" the raw html into "interpreted", and then onto the image...

Thanks!

Comment: The problem you're facing seems similar to this one. [Converting HTML to plain text in PHP for e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail/2564472). Perhaps that would of some help

Comment: I knew i was looking at the problem wrong. That looks like a good direction, thank you!!